# regex for mutate from substring

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I'm still learning my way around Regex, help much appreciated. I'm trying to extract the string from beginning of file name, aswell as last two characters from inside the square brackets of "File" below to generate "Image" and "ID" variables by mutate shown in data.out.

```
data<- data.frame("File"= c("TA1317_Scan3_Core[1,2,A]_[7473,42737]_component_data",
                     "TA 2654_Scan1_Core[1,3,A]_[6700,36673]_component_data")) 

data.out<- data %>% data.frame("Image"= c("TA1317", "TA2654"), "ID" = c("2A", "3A"))

                                                   File  Image ID
1  TA1317_Scan3_Core[1,2,A]_[7473,42737]_component_data TA1317 2A
2 TA 2654_Scan1_Core[1,3,A]_[6700,36673]_component_data TA2654 3A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is `strcapture`, with only one regex pattern instead of two:

```r
out <- strcapture("^([^_]*).*?\\[[^,]*,([^,]*,[^,*])\\].*", data$File, list(Image = "", ID = ""))
out$ID <- gsub(",", "", out$ID, fixed = TRUE)
out
#     Image ID
# 1  TA1317 2A
# 2 TA 2654 3A
cbind(data, out)
#                                                    File   Image ID
# 1  TA1317_Scan3_Core[1,2,A]_[7473,42737]_component_data  TA1317 2A
# 2 TA 2654_Scan1_Core[1,3,A]_[6700,36673]_component_data TA 2654 3A
```

Within a `dplyr` pipe, you can still use it:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  bind_cols(strcapture("^([^_]*).*?\\[[^,]*,([^,]*,[^,*])\\].*", .$File, list(Image = "", ID = ""))) %>%
  mutate(ID = gsub(",", "", ID, fixed = TRUE))
#                                                    File   Image ID
# 1  TA1317_Scan3_Core[1,2,A]_[7473,42737]_component_data  TA1317 2A
# 2 TA 2654_Scan1_Core[1,3,A]_[6700,36673]_component_data TA 2654 3A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
transform(data, Image = sub('([A-Z0-9\\s]+)_.*', '\\1', File), 
                ID = sub('.*\\[.*(\\d+),([A-Z])\\].*', '\\1\\2', File))

#                                                   File   Image ID
#1  TA1317_Scan3_Core[1,2,A]_[7473,42737]_component_data  TA1317 2A
#2 TA 2654_Scan1_Core[1,3,A]_[6700,36673]_component_data TA 2654 3A
```

where `Image` captures one or more occurrence of `A-Z`, `0-9` or whitespace.

and `ID` consists of a number followed by a comma and a letter between square brackets.